# How do i add a Clear Text Field button to my android app in C#?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

i'm very much a beginner with programming.. but i'm trying to develop a small android app using monodroid to store contacts in and call contacts from the address book.

Please forgive me if this is very simple but i have a text field and a button, both of which are in my Resources XML file and i want to be able to CLEAR the text in the textbox by clicking the button which will obviously be called 'Clear'.. all help is much appreciated as i'm looking forward to learning more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following layout, which I assume is similar to what you have already:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity's code you can do:

```
var clear = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Clear);
var textField = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextField);

clear.Click += (src, args) =>
               {
                   textField.Text = "";
               };
```

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your help, i'm still unsure where i am placing the activity code - here is what i have done but i am getting deployment errors like this.. should i put it inside a new public or private class.. thanks for being patient too, i know this must be painful for you!

Comment: public class Activity1 : Activity
 {
  int count = 1;

  protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
   SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

   var clear = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.clear);
   var textField = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textfield);
   
   clear.Click += (src, args) =>
   {
    textField.Text = "";
   };
  }

 }

Comment: I've got it working thank you very much Greg.. after checking over all the spellings i found some didn't match up to the names specified in the xml file! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
  Button ClearText=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ClearText);
  ClearText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v){
    EditText textedit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textedit);
    textedit.setText("");
  }
 });
```

clear must be registered as onclick handler for the button in the layout file like this

```
   <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ClearText"
    android:text="@string/ClearText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:onClick="clear"**          
    android:src="@drawable/clear"
    />
```

Comment: but youmight not be able to call your button clear as it might be a reserved word.

Comment: Hes reffering to monodroid. C#. Else the answer I had given http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html would have been good too